# Can I flash my phone with another region firmware?

Tags: rooting, rom-flashing, 7.0-nougat, huawei

I want to root my huawei phone but i've only found firmwares from another countries, would I have any problem if I flash my phone with any of these firmwares

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the firmware are made for your device you can flash it independently that it was made for a different country.

Take in mind that some countries have specific regulations regarding mobile devices, so some firmwares limit for example the wifi potence, the volume and/or the frequencies that the phone uses to work.

Comment: thanks, but now i got project menu in chinesse, hahahaha

Comment: So you have two options: find another rom or learn Chinese. Good luck...

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to break down the question: can you flash a custom rom that is used in another country? Yes you can.

The thing I'd be cautious about is flashing the part that is responsible for the communication itself. I think it's called "modem". Imagine there are are two countries and each operates on different transmission frequencies (900/1800/etc). If you flash incompatible version you may get into trouble making phone calls or connecting to the net at all.